# How to add and remove button dynamically from particular state in impromptu?

Tags: jquery, impromptu, impromptu-interface

I am using impromptu for prompt and I want to add buttons dynamically on specific condition.

```
state0: {
    html: 'Do you want to apply changes?',
    buttons: { YES: 1, NO: 0 },
    focus: 1,
    submit: function(e, v, m, f) {
        if (v == 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.prompt.goToState('state1');
            return false;
        }
        $.prompt.close();
    }
},
```

In this state I need 3 buttons for particular condition:
`"NEWCONFIG", "YES", "NO"`; and for another condition I need 2 buttons: `"YES", "NO"`

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: i want to show "NEWCONFIG" button on specific condition . It should not show all time on promt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a button variable before initializing your `impromptu` as below

```
var buttons={};
if(condition1)
{
   buttons = { YES: 1, NO: 0 };
}
else
{
   buttons ={ NEWCONFIG:1, YES:1, NO:0};
}
```

then initialize `impromptu`

```
state0: {
    html: 'Do you want to apply changes?',
    buttons: buttons,
    focus: 1,
    submit: function(e, v, m, f) {
        if (v == 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.prompt.goToState('state1');
            return false;
        }
        $.prompt.close();
    }
},
```

That's it.. Let me know if any problem!!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)